# Not authorized to perform operation (polkit authority not available and caller is not uid 0) (udisks-error-quark,3)

Tags: policykit

I've a Dell Precision Ultra-Speed Drive Quad x16 card installed in Dell 5820 workstation in which 4 x ADATA 2TB NVMe SSD drives.  Besides, 1 x Toshiba 2TB NVMe SSD drive (Ubuntu 18.04 boot) and 2 x SATA 16TB Segate IronWolf 3.5" HDD.

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.  I used GNOME Disks to format any of 4 x ADATA SSD drives, Segate 3.5" HDDs, it pops up the error of

> Error formatting volume
>   Not authorized to perform operation (polkit authority not available and caller is not uid 0) (udisks-error-quark,3).

I've no idea on this message.  Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I’m writing to follow up on my posting. I didn’t hear back from anyone on the team.

Comment: I have the same problem and have not found a solution.

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Dell laptop and a Sandisk USB drive.

Taking these steps solved my problem:

- Format the USB drive to FAT32 filesystem
- EJect the USB drive
- Restart the computer
- And now plugin the USB. it works fine.